# How to Override SaveChangesAsync in Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

How do I override SaveChangesAsync in Net Core Entity Framework?
Receiving the error below,

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    ApplyAuditInformation();
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

> Error: 'TestDBContext.SaveChangesAsync()': no suitable method found to override

Comment: I don't think your method signature is quite right.  According to the documentation, [DbContext.SaveChangesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=efcore-3.1) needs at least a CancellationToken as a parameter.

Comment: Why are you returning base ? Put for Await your ApplyAuditIIformation and return that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of `SaveChangesAsync` requires a `CancellationToken`.

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    ApplyAuditInformation();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

You'd only need to declare the method as `async` if you need to `await` something.

For example, if your `ApplyAuditInformation` needs to be "`await`ed":

```
public async override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    await ApplyAuditInformationAsync();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: And remember to override SaveChanges() as well, as the sync/async versions don't call each other.